# Moving average in Arduino IDE with distance sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors, moving-average

I was reviewing previous questions related to my topic, I found this: [Moving average in C++ with arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408868/moving-average-in-c-with-arduino)

The problem I have is very similar, but I want to relize distance averages every 150 seconds from a vl6180x adafruit distance sensor.

Average the first 150 seconds, print the result, then from the second 151 to 300 print the result and have it continue averaging my code.

I tried to do the same thing that is in the link I posted with my problem and I could not compile the code (I am programming from the Arduino IDE, and I am a beginner). My goal is to reduce the signal noise with moving average. My code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_VL6180X.h"
#define BUF_SIZE 15

Adafruit_VL6180X vl = Adafruit_VL6180X();
float array_calculate_avg(int * buf, int len);

int   buf[BUF_SIZE]   = {0};
int   buf_index       = 0;
float buf_avg         = 0.0;
int len


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // wait for serial port to open on native usb devices
  while (!Serial) {
    delay(1);
  }
  
  Serial.println("Adafruit VL6180x test!");
  if (! vl.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to find sensor");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Sensor found!");
}

void loop() {

   // Reset the index and start over.
    //
    if (BUF_SIZE == buf_index)
    {
        buf_index = 0;
    }

    buf[buf_index++] = vl.readRange();

    buf_avg = array_calculate_avg(buf, BUF_SIZE);

    Serial.print(buf_avg, 4);

    delay(2000);
    
  float lux = vl.readLux(VL6180X_ALS_GAIN_5);

  Serial.print("Lux: "); Serial.println(lux);
  
  uint8_t  range = vl.readRange();
  uint8_t  status = vl.readRangeStatus();

  if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_NONE) {
    Serial.print("Range: "); Serial.println(range);
  }

  // Some error occurred, print it out!
  
  if  ((status >= VL6180X_ERROR_SYSERR_1) && (status <= VL6180X_ERROR_SYSERR_5)) {
    Serial.println("System error");
  }
  else if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_ECEFAIL) {
    Serial.println("ECE failure");
  }
  else if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_NOCONVERGE) {
    Serial.println("No convergence");
  }
  else if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_RANGEIGNORE) {
    Serial.println("Ignoring range");
  }
  else if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_SNR) {
    Serial.println("Signal/Noise error");
  }
  else if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_RAWUFLOW) {
    Serial.println("Raw reading underflow");
  }
  else if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_RAWOFLOW) {
    Serial.println("Raw reading overflow");
  }
  else if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_RANGEUFLOW) {
    Serial.println("Range reading underflow");
  }
  else if (status == VL6180X_ERROR_RANGEOFLOW) {
    Serial.println("Range reading overflow");
  }
  delay(50);

 float
array_calculate_avg(int * buf, int len);
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        sum += buf[i];
    }

    return ((float) sum) / ((float) len);
}
```

My native language is not English. Apologies if I have gross grammatical errors :/

Comment: A quick scan and it looks like your `loop()` function is missing a closing brace `}` right before the `float array_calculate_avg(int * buf, int len);` which, btw, also has a semicolon `;` at the end, which it shouldn't.  You didn't tell what compilation error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help dear, it worked! It was a very silly mistake I was making, can I rate best answer tomorrow? because I want to do a test on the full system (now I don't have access to the system) and if I have any doubts  come back to this post. I am new here, i don't know if i should immediately rate the best solution.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loop()` function is missing a closing brace `}` right before the `float array_calculate_avg(int * buf, int len);` line which, btw, also has a semicolon `;` at the end, which it shouldn't.